# Why Array.Reverse(myCharArray) and not myCharArray=myCharArray.Reverse?

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

I'm new to programming. I'm learning c# through Bob Tabors videos on Channel 9.

Can you explain why we cannot do something like this:

```
string mijnVoornaam = "Remolino";
char[] mijnCharArray = mijnVoornaam.ToCharArray();
mijnCharArray = mijnCharArray.Reverse();
```

instead of this:

```
string mijnVoornaam = "Remolino";
char[] mijnCharArray = mijnVoornaam.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(mijnCharArray);
```

Comment: Another reason is that in your suggested alternative, a modified copy of the array is returned (presumably leaving the original array untouched). This would be more expensive. However it is a good question as to why there is no 'public void Reverse()' method.

Comment: You could use the extension method `Reverse` http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb358497.aspx

Comment: Also note you don't need to ToCharArray before the reverse, a string is already an IEnumerable<char> IntelliSense just hides the linq autocompletion for strings to avoid missuse

Answer (score 4):

You can do both.

First it performed using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), it creates a new sequence:

```
using System.Linq;

mijnCharArray = mijnCharArray.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Second makes changes in-place, is optimized and more efficient:

```
Array.Reverse(mijnCharArray);
```

Choice is yours, depends on your usage scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Because the first uses the `LINQ` extension method [`Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358497(v=vs.100).aspx) which returns an `IEnumerable<char>` instead of `char[]`. So you could do...

```
mijnCharArray = mijnCharArray.Reverse().ToArray();
```

but that would be less efficient than [`Array.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx) since it has to create a new array and it doesn't know the final size beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Actually; you can.

`.Reverse` is a LINQ extension method, and returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which is why the assignment fails. However, if you did this:

```
string mijnVoornaam = "Remolino";
char[] mijnCharArray = mijnVoornaam.ToCharArray();
mijnCharArray = mijnCharArray.Reverse().ToArray();
```

It would work just fine. Note that this returns a *new* array with the characters reversed.

`Array.Reverse` does an in-place reversal, and so returns `void` and you can't assign the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do that if you use `System.Linq`, but that's an extension method for IEnumerable.

Comment: `char[]` is `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `Reverse` extension method since `Reverse()` returns `IEnumerable<char>`, which is not `char[]`. You have to cast the `IEnumerable<char>` to an array. So this works for example:

```
char[] c = mijnVoornaam.Reverse().ToArray();
```

You could use `Reverse` on `string` too with this extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string Reverse(this string s)
    {
        return string.Concat(s.Reverse());
        // or:
        // return new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
string reverse = "name".Reverse();
```

Comment: Yes, `char[]` *does* implement `IEnumerable`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx - This is working: `"test".ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray()`

Comment: @StephanBauer: You are right, my bad. Misread the error message.

Comment: no need to create a new string and call .ToArray(); just use Concat: `string reversedFirstName = string.Concat(mijnVoornaam.Reverse())`;